# Datatable select method ORDER BY clause

Tags: .net, select, datatable, methods, sql-order-by

I 'm trying to sort the rows in my datatable using select method.
I know that i can say

```
datatable.select("col1='test'")
```

which in effect is a where clause and will return n rows that satisfy the condition.

I was wondering can i do the following

`datatable.select("ORDER BY col1")` ---col1 is the name of the column

I tried `datatable.defaultview.sort()` but didnt work

Any ideas on how to get around this issue.
thanks

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Have you tried using the [DataTable.Select(filterExpression, sortExpression) method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/way3dy9w.aspx)?

Answer (score 30):

Use

```
datatable.select("col1='test'","col1 ASC")
```

Then before binding your data to the grid or repeater etc, use this

```
datatable.defaultview.sort()
```

That will solve your problem.

Comment: yes. I was looking for the same issue and found the solution somehwere, tested it and then posted here.

Answer (score 23):

You can use the below simple method of sorting:

```
datatable.DefaultView.Sort = "Col2 ASC,Col3 ASC,Col4 ASC";
```

By the above method, you will be able to sort N number of columns.

Comment: The DefaultView.Sort worked great!! Made is wicked easy thank you!!