# Maintain the Order of the Rows of Datatable in VB.NET on select Query

Tags: vb.net, datatable

When i tried to run a Select query like below to a dataTable in VB.NET.

```
Dim rows As DataRow = DSXML.Tables(0).Select("EMPNO Like '" + txtToBeSearched + "%'").FirstOrDefault
```

But it is returning the first row after ordering the rows based on EMPNO column.
How to avoid the default ordering of the rows in the above code?

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274976/datatable-select-method-order-by-clause

Answer (score 0):

Try this (assuming that there are no NULL or Nothing values in the column)

```
DSXML.Tables(0).FirstOrDefault(Function(X) CStr(X("EMPNO")).Contains(txtToBeSearched))
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the below one working fine.

```
Dim rows = From r In dataTable.AsEnumerable() Where r.Field(Of String)("EMPNO") Like "*" & txtToBeSearched & "*"

Dim row As DataRow = rows(0)
```

To get the first row.